# Styling MTableToolbar elements

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to style my MaterialTable component. Some of the components are easy to do so because you can override the styles with createMuiTheme(). What I really have are two components, MuiFormControl and MTableToolbar, and I want to put them inline.

I did sucessfully with MuiFormControl:

```
const getMuiTheme = () =>
    createMuiTheme({
        overrides: {
            MuiFormControl: {
                root: {
                    display: 'inline-block'
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

However I am unable to do the same with MTableToolbar component. The class name that actually shows up is named "MTableToolbar-actions-36" so I actually want to change an action section the MTableToolbar. The components looks like this (and MTableToolbar it's the icons section):

[image]

I don't want to create a css rule for "MTableToolbar-actions-36" as there might be a way to do this without a css rule.